# How to gzip multiple files into one gz file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gzip

I have 100 files: `cvd1.txt`, `cvd2.txt` ... `cvd100.txt`

How to `gzip` 100 files into one `.gz` file, so that after I `gunzip` it, I  should have `cvd1.txt`, `cvd2.txt` ... `cvd100.txt` separately?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

if you have zip,

```
zip myzip.zip cvd*.txt
```

Don't need to `tar` them first.

Comment: @Kurumi- Do Windows programmes such as Winzip or 7-zip recognise .zip files?

Comment: @Tony. I believe they do. I tested the 7-zip linux version with zip and able to extract. If you want, there is also GNU zip for windows.

Comment: You lose `zgrep`, `zcmp`, `zdiff` and all sorts of tools that can work on pipes by your choice of a non-streamable format called zip. Power users use pipes.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This answer tells the OP to use `zip` which creates ZIP files, not `.gz` files.

Answer (score 116):

You want to `tar` your files together and `gzip` the resulting tar file.

```
tar cvzf cvd.tar.gz cvd*.txt
```

To untar the gzip'd tar file you would do:

```
tar xvzf cvd.tar.gz -C /path/to/parent/dir
```

This would extract your files under the `/path/to/parent/dir` directory

Comment: if you name the file with the extension .tgz, (short for tar gz), then Windows programs will recognize it as something that winzip etc can process as is. Congrats to SiegeX for your 10K!

Answer (score 36):

You'll want to use tar, like so:

`tar -czvf file.tar.gz cvd*.txt`

tar puts the files together, while gzip then performs the compression.

Quoth the gzip manpage:

> If  you  wish  to create a single archive file with multiple members so that members can later be extracted independently, use an archiver such as  tar or zip. GNU tar supports the -z option to invoke gzip transparently. gzip is designed as a complement to tar, not as a replacement

Answer (score 16):

gzip by itself does not know anything about file structure.  To do what you want, you need to first put the files into some kind of container file (e.g. a tar structure, or similar) and then gzip that.  tar has z and j (for bzip2) switches on GNU platforms to do this.

Comment: The switch is actually 'z' ('x' is for extract).  Nice you mentioned 'j'/bzip2 - much tighter compression.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using:

```
zip my_final_filename.zip my_first_file my_second_file ... my_last_file

unzip my_final_filename.gz
```

or

```
tar cvzf my_final_filename.tar.gz my_first_file my_second_file ... my_last_file

tar -czvf my_final_filename.tar.gz
```

Unfortunately `gzip` is not capable of doing that. In case of more information please look at comments.

Comment: I don't think your first command works. At least generally. If it works for a particular shell you should indicate it. I'd downvote if I had enough rep.

Comment: @DPM is right, the `gzip/gunzip` commands didn't work, it will return the error `gzip: my_final_filename.gz: No such file or directory`

Comment: DPM and Bilal are right. Gzip is not capable of compressing multiple files into one. Look at this thread under Melebius answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103018/gzip-2-files-into-one-file
I edit my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

To compress multiple files with different patterns, we could this :

```
tar -czvf deploy.tar.gz **/Alice*.yml **/Bob*.json
```

this will add all .yml files that starts with Alice from any sub-directory and add all .json files that starts with Bob from any sub-directory.

Comment: Already answered in https://superuser.com/a/334830/107419