# How to gzip more than one file using cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to gzip multiple files into one gz file?](https://superuser.com/questions/334827/how-to-gzip-multiple-files-into-one-gz-file)

I am trying to gzip a bunch of files in the same folder using cgywin on windows 7.  When I try

```
gzip *.*
```

I can't seem to specify a gzip filename to put all the files into. 
All files are gzipped separately.  Is it possible to gzip the collection of them into the file?

Comment: As for the question - use tar to make 1 file then gzip to compress it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not gzip collection. You use PAX or CPIO or TAR to make it.

`gzip *.*` is useless.

DOS would take `gzip .`
UNIX would use `gzip *`

```
tar cfz file.tgz dir/ dir/ dir/ file dir/file

tar tvfz file.tgz
tar xvfz file.tgz
```