# Unable to create a *.gz archieve

Tags: command-line, bash, freebsd, archiving

Trying to create a .gz archive - my_gz.gz -  and add multiple files to it:

```
  $ gzip my_gz.gz file1.txt file12.txt

  gzip: can't stat: my_gz.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to gzip multiple files into one gz file?](https://superuser.com/questions/334827/how-to-gzip-multiple-files-into-one-gz-file)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add multiple files using `gzip` because it is only a compression program, not an archiver. To compress multiple files, you would want to use `tar` with `gzip`:

```
tar czf archive.tar.gz file1.txt file2.txt
```

The `z` tells the archiver to automatically use `gzip` for compression. You could also tell it to use different compression algorithm. See the [`tar(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar) manual page for more information on this.